# How do I Deserialize Just a String with Namespace?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://www.example.com">Message received</string>
```

I prefer to deserialize using an extension method like so:

```
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub DeserializeFromXML(ByRef objTarget As Object, ByVal strXML As String)

        Dim objXMLSerializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objTarget.GetType())
        Dim objStringReader As New System.IO.StringReader(strXML)
        objTarget = objXMLSerializer.Deserialize(objStringReader)

    End Sub
```

Example:

```
Dim strExample As String = String.Empty
strExample.DeserializeFromXML(strXML)
```

This is failing because of the namespace (it works without it).  I can't create a new class that inherits from String because it in non-inheritable (for the sake of using attributes to define the namespace).  How can I deserialize a simple XML string with a namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar thing but this was done using C#.NET.

Please see if this works for you.

```
    public static object DeserializeXmlWithNameSpaceToObject(Type ObjectType, string xml)
    {
        object result = null;

        // identify the namespace, without a matching namespace the xml can't be serialized
        string defaultNameSpace = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(new StringReader(xml));
        defaultNameSpace = document.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;

        // Set the xml reader settings
        XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xrs.CheckCharacters = false;

        // Deserialize the xml into an object
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, xrs))
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ObjectType, defaultNameSpace);
                result = ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
            }
        }

        // return the object
        return result;
    }
```

Used an [online tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to convert this C#.NET code to VB.NET.
Here is the converted VB.NET code.

```
Public Shared Function DeserializeXmlWithNameSpaceToObject(ObjectType As Type, xml As String) As Object
    Dim result As Object = Nothing

    ' identify the namespace, without a matching namespace the xml can't be serialized
    Dim defaultNameSpace As String = String.Empty
    Dim document As New XmlDocument()
    document.Load(New StringReader(xml))
    defaultNameSpace = document.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI

    ' Set the xml reader settings
    Dim xrs As New XmlReaderSettings()
    xrs.CheckCharacters = False

    ' Deserialize the xml into an object
    Using sr As New StringReader(xml)
        Using xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr, xrs)
            Dim ser As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ObjectType, defaultNameSpace)
            result = ser.Deserialize(New StringReader(xml))
        End Using
    End Using

    ' return the object
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I was able to figure out the issue from this code.  Such a simple answer: Use the DefaultNamespace Overload on the Serializer's Constructor.